# How do i remove a item from a Listbox when it has been chosen and a button has been pressed

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, listbox

I am creating a application to be used on a fridge, so that the user can see the items in the fridge by a List box on a GUI screen and then when they remove a item they can press on that item on the list box and press remove where that item will be removed from the List box.

However I have come across a problem in terms of how do I remove a item from a list by using the button (If That Makes Any sense).

Here is my code;

```
  def Pud():
        window = Tk()
        window.title('Listbox Example')

        def dialog():
***#########Somehere around here i belive should be where the item is removed from the list box########***

            box.showinfo('Selection','Item taken from the fridge: \n'+ \
            listbox.get(listbox.curselection()))

        frame = Frame(window)

        listbox = Listbox(window)
        listbox.pack()
        Items_In_Fridge = ['Milk', 'Butter']
        for widget in Items_In_Fridge:
            listbox.insert(0, widget)

        btn = Button(window,text = 'Remove This Item',command=dialog)

        btn.pack(side = RIGHT,padx = 5)
        listbox.pack(side = LEFT)

        window.mainloop()
```

I know where the code should be however I am not sure what the code is or how to format it in terms of what I need, I have done multiple methods of trying to complete this but without being successful.

Any help would be greatly appreciated I am using python 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capture the response of your dialog. If the user says 'yes', delete the item.

```
response = messagebox.askquestion ('Delete Item','Delete the item taken from the fridge?\n'+ \
    listbox.get(listbox.curselection()))
if response == 'yes':
    listbox.delete(listbox.curselection())
```

Comment: Thank you, I honestly didn't think of a askquestion box.